# How to make custom Word-Addin check for misspellings using Office-js API

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I want to create a word-addin that will show error (underline the misspelled words in red curvy line) for misspelled words. Also, like in word when you misspelled a word it shows red line and when you right click it, it gives some suggestions for correct words. I am trying to make that for Bangla language using Office-js. I have not found any tutorial regarding this.

I have seen the office documentations. There is an API for enabling dictionary in word: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/dictionary-task-pane-add-ins . I am hoping to find a similar thing but for checking misspelling words. Also if there is option for context based misspelling then it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dictionaries for Word: [How to add a custom dictionary in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322198/how-to-add-a-custom-dictionary-in-word). This would make use of the existing, very fast, real-time, Word spell checker. If making spell check possible for writers of Bangla is your goal, then I think this is what you should do.

If you must have an add-in rather than a dictionary, please respond and we can think of how you might implement one with an add-in.

Comment: Yes, I want to have an add-in. I want to show misspelled word. Both context-free (non word errors) and context based (real world error). And I want it to work like the dictionary in real world time. (Not like when you click a button and then it will check the whole document. I want it to keep checking whenever there is a change in a sentence).